# Meaningless output from LibSVM

Tags: c++, libsvm

I am working on a Support Vector Machine in C++ for my University using LibSVM.
For that I want to be able to parse .csv files filled with documents and labels.
This works so far pretty well but as output I get

```
C = nan
obj = nan, rho = nan
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 0
```

and this does not look like good data was generated.

I bet I am making a beginner's mistake but can simply not figure out what is going wrong. The following shows how I create the nodes, as well as the Document class I use, which is supposed to be analysed.

```
class Document {
public:
    double docID;
    double label;
    std::string text;
    Document(double docID, double label, std::string aText);
}
```

...

```
std::vector<Feature> features = getFeatures();
documents = getDocuments();

int documentCount = documents.size();
int featureCount = features.size();
svm_node** nodesList = new svm_node*[documentCount];
double* labelList = new double[documentCount];

for (int j = 0; j < documentCount; j++){
        nodesList[j] = new svm_node[featureCount];
        Document currentDocument = documents[j];
        for (int i = 0; i < featureCount; i++) {
            svm_node node;
            node.index = i + 1;
            node.value = features[i].analyse(currentDocument.docID);
            nodesList[j][i] = node;
        }
        labelList[j] = currentDocument.label;
    }

problem->l = documentCount;
problem->x = nodesList;
problem->y = labelList;

param->svm_type = NU_SVC;
param->kernel_type = LINEAR;
param->degree = 3;
param->gamma = 0.0625;
param->coef0 = 0;
param->nu = 0.25;
param->cache_size = 100;
param->C = 1;
param->eps = 1e-3;
param->p = 0.1;
param->shrinking = 1;
param->probability = 0;
param->nr_weight = 0;
param->weight = new double[2];
param->weight_label = new int[2];
param->weight[0] = 1;
param->weight_label[0] = 1;
param->weight[1] = 1;
param->weight_label[1] = 1;

svm_check_parameter(problem, param);
model = svm_train(problem, param);
```

Does somebody know where the reason could lie for the meaninglessness of the output?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your feature files, is everything in order ? no nan's, inf's or very large numbers?
2. Is your training data skewed ? i.e. you have a lots of values for one class, but hardly any for the other class.